# How many years does it take to convert an L1 visa into a Green Card?

Tags: usa, greencard, l1-visa

Assuming one is employed on a L-1B visa, how long would it take for them to receive a Green Card? And how long before they are able to initiate the Green Card process?

Comment: Related https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11236/is-it-possible-to-eventually-convert-an-l-1b-visa-to-a-green-card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two have nothing to do with each other. L1 is a nonimmigrant visa. It has nothing to do with the process of getting permanent residency.

To become a permanent resident through an employment-based category, the employer must petition you (there are certain subcategories that can self-petition). You working for an employer on L1, H1b, or any other status does not mean they will ever petition you to immigrate. An employer could petition you as soon as they want, or after as long a period as they want, or never at all.

And if an employer decides to petition you, there is no requirement for you to be in any particular status. You could be in the US in L1, H1b, F1, B2, or any other status, or you could be not in the US at all, when they petition you. The only requirement is that the employer offers to employ you once you become a permanent resident; there is no requirement that you currently work, or have ever worked, for that employer.

Comment: So how many years does it take once initiated?

Comment: @JonathanReez: Depending on the particular category and your country of birth, there may or may nor be a several-year wait for visa numbers.

Comment: Is there a site where I can find the wait times per country of birth?

Comment: Is it really dependant on country of birth, or is it actually country of citizenship?  (I am pretty sure I know the answer, but many people seem to use the terms loosely and virtually interchangeably, so it probably makes sense to be extra precise.)

Comment: @phoog: it's country of birth, not nationality

Comment: @JonathanReez: The [visa bulletin](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-bulletin.html) for each month lists the priority dates for which a visa number is available now for each category and country of birth (i.e. applications initiated that long ago are not able to proceed to the next step). From that you can estimate the wait for visa numbers. The ones that are "C" currently have no wait for visa numbers, though the applications still take time.